# IBM MQ cmit and rollback with syncpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-mq

**Infra-Overview:**

I have a setup where I am reading a set of messages from IBM MQ and processing those messages in k8 cluster env and sending it to the destination host.

**Issue:**

I observed that sometimes the flow of the messages is huge and before sending it to the destination host our pod gets failed and restarts, by this we are losing all the messages as we are following a read-and-delete approach from [ibmmq example](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsget.js)

**Expected Solution:**

I am looking for a solution where, until these messages are sent to the destination host, we don't lose the track of the messages.

**What I tried:**

We have a concept of `unit of work` in IBM MQ but since we can't expect a delay in reading and processing, I can't wait for a single message to get processed and then read the another message as it might have a major performance setback.

**Code language:**

NodeJs

Comment: Do you GET from one queue manager and PUT to a different queue manager?

Comment: @JoshMc no, I am not putting it in queue.Posting data to destination host with rest api.

Comment: You could open multiple connections to MQ and each can have a different message GET under syncpoint.

Comment: @JoshMc is this the only solution we have ?

Comment: You said "I can't wait for a single message to get process then read another..".  So my suggestion is just to do things in parallel.  Can you explain more how you would want things to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments suggest there are a number of ways to skin this cat, but you will need to use transactions.

As soon as you create the connection with the transaction option, the transaction scope begins. This gets closed and next transaction begins when you either commit or rollback.

So you should handle the messages in batches, that make sense to your application, and commit when the batch is complete. If your application is killed by k8s then all uncommitted read messages will get rolled back, via back out queue process to stop poison messages.

> Section added to show sample code, and explanation of backout queues.
>
> > In your normal processing, if an app gets stopped before it has had time to process the message, you will want that message returned to the queue. So that the message is still available to be processed.

> > To enable this rollback you need to `or` in the `MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT` into the get message options

```
gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
```

> > Then if all goes well, you can commit.

```
  mq.Cmit(hConn, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      debug_warn('Error on commit', err);
    } else {
      debug_info('Commit was successful');
    }
  });
```

> > or rollback

```
  mq.Back(hConn, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      debug_warn('Error on rollback', err);
    } else {
      debug_info('rollback was successful');
    }
  });
```

> > If you rollback, the message goes back to the queue. Which means it is also the next message that your app will read. This can generate a poison message loop. So you should also set up a `backout queue` with `pass all context` permissions for your app user and a `backout threshold`.

> > Say you set the threshold to 5. The message can be read 5 times, with rollback. Your app needs to check the threshold and decide that it is a poison message and move it off the queue.

> > To check the backout threshold (and the backout queue name) you can use the following code

```
    // Remember to or in the Inquire option on the Open
    openOptions |= MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;

...
    attrs = [ new mq.MQAttr(MQC.MQIA_BACKOUT_THRESHOLD), 
             new mq.MQAttr(MQC.MQCA_BACKOUT_REQ_Q_NAME) ];

    mq.Inq(hObj, attrs, (err, selectors) => {
        if (err) {
          debug_warn('Error retrieving backout threshold', err);
        } else {
          debug_info('Attributes have been found');

          selectors.forEach((s) => {
              switch (s.selector) {
                case MQC.MQIA_BACKOUT_THRESHOLD:
                debug_info('Threshold is ', s.value);
                break;
              case MQC.MQCA_BACKOUT_REQ_Q_NAME:
                debug_info('Backout queue is ', s.value);
                break;
           }
          });
        }
      });
```

> > When getting the message your app can use mqmd.BackoutCount to check how often the message has been rolled back.

```
    if (mqmd.BackoutCount >= threshold) {
      ...
    }
```

> > What I have noticed, that if this is in the same application instance that is repeatedly calling rollback on the same message, then at the threshold a `MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR` error is thrown. Which your app can check for, and then discard the message.
> > If its a different app instance then it doesn't get the `MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR` error, so it can check the backout threshold and can discard the message, remembering to commit the discard action.

> > See https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/transactions/JMS/SE for more information.

As an alternative you could use keda - https://keda.sh - which works with k8s
to monitor your queue depth and scale according to the number of messages waiting to be processed, as opposed to CPU / memory consumption. That way you can scale up when there are lots of messages waiting to be processed, and slowly scale down then the queue becomes manageable. Here is a link to getting started - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Go-K8s - the example is for a Go app, but equally applies to Node.js

Comment: from javascript perspective, I don't see suffient examples related to ibmmq. Due to this there is a lot of struggle.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using sync point with these options:    gmo.Options =MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;  the transaction is not working, it continuously reads the msg, I was expecting it would read and wait for the cmit or rollback interval and then proceed with the next one, any clue why this is happening ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a code snippet and an explanation of the rollback mechanism. I think you might be missing a back out threshold.

Comment: @PrabhatMishra is the problem that the same message is displayed over and over or that the message you have on the queue is read and no longer available even if you did not cmit the message? If the later this can be explained by "[If an application disconnects (MQDISC) from a queue manager while a global unit of work coordinated by IBM® MQ is still active, an attempt is made to commit the unit of work.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026870_.htm)".  In the sample program the cleanup func is called which issues `Disc`, this itself will cmit the UOW.

Comment: chughts, while `MQPMO_SYNCPOINT` and `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` have the same value, it is much less to confusing to use the later as a Get Message Option. Also can you confirm if the node js libraries provided by IBM have implemented backout logic? In normal MQ APIs provided by the core product only the JMS and XMS APIs provide built in backout logic. Since node js is built on top of the MQ C API libraries which do not include backout logic, it would need to be implemented in the node js layer. I did a quick search in the github repo and didn't note any specific implementation of backout logic.

Comment: JoshMc, you are right, the Node.js app needs to check the backout count on the message and determine that it can't be processed and remove it from the queue. For JMS and XMS this is done by the libraries, but for Node.js, which is based on the C API it is the app's responsibility.

Comment: Hi chughts, the JMS logic is described in this [KC page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.html), but in summary the first time it comes across a message with BO count greater than 0 on a queue that is being consumed it opens the queue for inquiry (separate from the existing handle) and checks BOTHRESH and BOQNAME.  It is also good to note that if the queue open is a QALIAS to a QLOCAL that the resolved QLOCAL most be opened for inquiry, in short, the IBM JMS (and related XMS) logic related to poison message handling is not straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and providing sample code.  I wonder if coming up with some good "JMS like" samples of poison message handling in various APIs that do not natively support it would be something of general interest, I know that I would promote it to my user base.  IBM employees providing the samples would have the benefit of looking at a good reference implementation in the JMS code and a good resource in Paul Titheridge.

Comment: @chughts you got the issue right, it's the poison msg and the Backout threshold is not yet implemented, I am excited to implement it. The next thing I had is, what if there is some application issue and the msg is not able to reach to the commit point, In this case all the messages would term out as poison msg?  so what should we do in this case ? any suggestion ?

Comment: Provided their backout count is less than the threshold then they haven't yet been designated at poison. Which means that they can be processed subsequently.

Comment: Okay @chughts this means, all msg might get termed out as poison msg when there would be an issue while committing. This would continue until it gets noticed.

Comment: Monitor the backout queue, alert when messages hit the queue, or monitor the application logs and alert when the app moves a message to the backout queue.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Thanks 

Comment: Hi @chughts, I have implemented above backout feature and made changes so that application always Backsout but getting same below information always.
Attributes have been found
selectors values -->  [ { selector: 22, value: 0 }, { selector: 2019, value: '' } ]
Threshold is  0
Backout queue is  
BackOut count --->  0

Comment: As we are moving onto questions on how to set up backout threshold and backout queue properties on queues, I think this should be raised as a separate question. In essence you need to modify the properties on your queue, or your admin will need to modify the properties, as currently they seem to be not set.

Comment: @chughts, any thoughts on my prior comment about " coming up with some good "JMS like" samples of poison message handling in various APIs that do not natively support it"?

Comment: @JoshMc I also think that it is needed - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/issues/42