# Backout Count reaches to infinite loop in IBM MQ

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

**Issue Background:**

I have used the [Ibmmq npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmmq) package in our NodeJS Project as the source of input is Apache Ibmmq. Everything seems to be working fine as per our implementation except one thing. To handle the erroneous msg we have used ibmmq cmit and rollback feature of ibmmq. 
Singnnificance of `cmit` and `rollback` is: 
 whenever the msg processing is successful we place a `cmit` on the msg so that the msg gets deleted from IBM MQ queue.
For handling errors with the msg of in processing we want to retry processing due to this we use the `rollback` feature as in `Backout Msg` once the Backout on the msg is done, the msg comes again for processing until it has reached the `Backout Threshold`   in our case it's 3. So after 3 retry's the msg should automatically move to the backout queue.

**Issue:**
Once the Backout Threshold is reached the msg now comes again for processing, the msg is not moving to the `Backout Queue`  automatically. Due to this, this was resulting in an infinite loop of the same msg processing by our service. To Overcome this issue, i now place a cmit on the msg if `Backout Count >= Backout Threshold` and log this msg. But this is kind of manual task of picking that msg from logs and reprocessing those.
**Expected Solution:** Once the `Backout Count >= Backout Threshold` the msg should automatically move to backout queue.
**What i tried** I thougt, initially it was The issue with the server where this IBM MQ was hosted and theey have some issue. But when I connected with them, they said, There might be some issue with our npm client and everything is working fine at their end. now i am clueless what configuration i need to do.

I request to please help me here.

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680808/ibm-mq-cmit-and-rollback-with-syncpoint?noredirect=1#comment114366145_64680808) approach for IBM MQ `cmit` and `rollback` implementation.

Comment: @chughts could you please help here too ?

Comment: Looks like you missed reading one finer point in @chugts reply in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680808/ibm-mq-cmit-and-rollback-with-syncpoint?noredirect=1#comment114366145_64680808 where he said "the Node.js app needs to check the backout count on the message and determine that it can't be processed and remove it from the queue. For JMS and XMS this is done by the libraries, but for Node.js, which is based on the C API it is the app's responsibility."

Comment: okay thanks @Shashi for highlighting. I have raised a github issue to cross verify this functionality implementation https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/issues/111

Comment: Only JMS and XMS have built in BO logic.

Comment: @JoshMc is pushing msg to backout queue is like we need to create a new connection with the backout queue ? or same connection object can be re-used ?

Comment: The same connection to the queue manager can be used, but you would need to open the back out queue to place the message on it.